# HTML5/Javascript - Trying to get bind a canvas animation to a keyboard event

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This is my first time doing keyboard events in javascript, but I know for a fact the animation works. The idea is very simple:To play an animation of a rectangle moving when the user presses enter. Below is my code.

```
//Event listeners
window.addEventListener("keydown", onKeyDown, false);

function onKeyDown(event){
    var keyCode = event.keyCode;
    switch(keyCode){
        case 13  //enter
            drawStuff();
        break;
    }
}

//code to be executed onKeyDown
function drawStuff(){
var x = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvas = x.getContext('2d');

var i = 0;

function animate(){
    if(i < 451){
        canvas.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
        canvas.fillStyle="red";
        canvas.fillRect(30,i,50,50);
        i++;
    }
    else{}
}

window.setInterval(animate, 1);
}
```

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: 1) not sure if typo or problem: should be `case 13:` (colon missing) 2) Holding enter down will create multiple intervals (no bueno). 3) You aren't clearing the interval when the animation is done, causing `animate` to be called FOREVER!

Comment: 4) Intervals aren't the correct tool for the job anyways, look into `requestAnimationFrame` (and the shim for it)

Comment: 5) Your example seems to animate correctly with the missing colon where it should be. `case 13:`

Comment: requestAnimationFrame is all fine and good, but its not well supported. Therefore I really can't make use of it

Comment: That's what shims/polyfills are for.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [`requestAnimationFrame` shim](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) by Paul Irish; rAF has many advantages over the setInterval method; mainly that it is built for doing exactly this, but also it only requests frames when the browser is ready, so it pauses stuff happening when your website is in the background. I've also noticed smoother performance when I switched over.

I'd say something like this should work:

```
var animationHasTriggered = false;
var x = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var canvas = x.getContext('2d');
var keysDown = {};

var i = 0;

window.addEventListener('load', function()
{
    addEventListener("keydown", function(e)
    {
        keysDown[e.keyCode] = true;
    }, false);

    addEventListener("keyup", function(e)
    {
        delete keysDown[e.keyCode];
    }, false);

    updateAll();

}, false);

function updateAll()
{
    if (13 in keysDown || animationHasTriggered)
    {
        animationHasTriggered = true;
        animate();
    }
    requestAnimationFrame(updateAll);
}

function animate()
{
    if (i < 451)
    {
        canvas.clearRect(0,0,500,500);
        canvas.fillStyle="red";
        canvas.fillRect(30,i,50,50);
        i++;
    }
    else
    {
        animationHasTriggered = false;
    }
}
(function()
{
    // http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x)
    {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame) window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element)
    {
        var currTime = new Date().getTime();
        var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
        var id = window.setTimeout(function()
        {
            callback(currTime + timeToCall);
        }, timeToCall);
        lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
        return id;
    };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame) window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id)
    {
        clearTimeout(id);
    };
}());
```